# Why does the RFC 5280 dictate the CAs not to issue certificates with negative serial numbers?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, x.509, serial

I have tried to issue a certificate beginning with 8 to F but I have found it is impossible, mostly due to the RFC:

> The serial number MUST be a positive integer assigned by the CA to
>   each certificate. It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a
>   given CA (i.e., the issuer name and serial number identify a unique
>   certificate). CAs MUST **force the *serialNumber* to be a non-negative
>   integer**.

So I would like to know if there is any actual reason not to do that beyond the "buggy ASN.1  implementation"?

Comment: Please see this answer regarding why serial numbers should be random http://security.stackexchange.com/q/15690/396

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** because [RFC 3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459), its predecessor, says so.

**Longer answer:** because historically ASN.1 encoders/decoders have had problems with properly encoding and decoding integers.

X.509 uses [DER encoded ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding), which amongst other things, means that the data must be encoded in its minimal (shortest) form. As integers are stored in a variable length twos-complement form, in order to properly encode a non-negative integer which happens to have its leading bit (MSB) set, it must be padded with a leading zero, which in other circumstance is disallowed.
The wording of X.690([http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf‎](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf%E2%80%8E) )
is such that the leading 9 bits of an integer must be inspected in order to verify the minimal form, thus allowing such positive integers to have leading 0 byte.

To [quote Peter Gutmann](http://lists.asn1.org/pipermail/asn1/2013-January/000959.html)

> There's a second but: Historically many encoders have gotten the signedness of
> integers wrong, which means that (a) if you get a negative number (at least in
> the area of crypto, which I'm most familiar with) it's always an encoding
> error and never a deliberate use of a negative value, and (b) because of the
> widespread use of incorrect encoders, many decoders treat all integer values
> as unsigned.  So while you can use negative values in theory, it's not a good
> idea in practice.

The correct determination of serial numbers is *critical* when it comes to revocation checks. Ambiguity is an enemy.

It seems to me that this is *exactly* the problem your encoder is having...

Comment: It is really surprising something to become standarized mostly due to implementation faults. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Because a serial number is designed to be a non-negative incrementing number.

It's basically an inventory control code for a CA, and they are non-negative incrementing numbers in most inventory systems.

Comment: This makes little to no sense. The current standard practice is to use a randomly generated value for the `serialNumber` in an X.509 certificate.

Comment: Current standard practice is unrelated to what it was *designed* for.